# android:maxLength not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm using a Froyo emulator with an EditText element and android:maxLength="100". Even so, I can't type more than 30 characters into the EditText element. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the emulator.

I have the same problem with a Froyo-Emulator. After reading your question I tried it with a Gingerbread-Emulator and had the same problem (not more than 30 chars). I also tried switching to landscape which did not change anything. My Gingerbread-Hardware-Device accepts more than 30 characters into the same EditText.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing the `android:width` and `android:height` attributes?

You may also wish to try deleting the R.java file from the gen folder and building the project again and cleaning it as sometimes the XML isn't regenerated properly when it is changed.

Comment: OK, this is strange. I can type lots of characters into the EditText (more than 30). But I can't type the following text: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET (which happens to be the name of an Android constant). I get stopped after "WHEN_" I also can't type 0123456789012345678901234567890 (I get stopped after the "9".) There's some kind of filtering going on, but I don't know what filtering is making this happen.

Comment: Could you post the XML for the layout? Or wherever the EditText is referenced in your code?

Comment: <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Flags"></TextView>
   
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:maxLength="100"></EditText>

Comment: The XML is fine, you could try doing it programmatically using input filters, which is the counterpart to the `android:maxLength` property. Here is a [link](http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/02/maxlength-in-edittext-using-codes.html) to an example of it being done.